# Prevent website being accessed NOT via the intended domain name

Tags: nginx, redirect, tls

I have an nginx server on Debian with multiple domains. They all live in the html folder. Then the A records are pointed to my server and you can access the files in `/var/www/html/mywebsite.biz` by going to https://mywebsite.biz. I also assign them TLS certs using Let's Encrypt.

It looks like this:

```
└── html
    ├── mywebsite.biz
    ├── anotherwebsite.net
    ├── example-three.com
    └── somewebsite.ca
```

However, you can access that `html` folder without TLS via my ip address like this:

http://216.58.216.78/mywebsite.biz

But I also have cases where I would want that to happen. e.g. if I want to set up a test site before I can point the domain to my server. For this, I used noip.com to assign it a friendly name like this:

http://myservername.ddns.net/somewebsite.ca (just a test site)

**What's the best way to deny access via the ip address/friendly name for only some sites?**

Deny/redirect these:

http://myservername.ddns.net/mywebsite.biz

http://216.58.216.78/mywebsite.biz

Allow this:

http://myservername.ddns.net/somewebsite.ca

My guess is to just redirect them there, but I'm a bit new with nginx and want to make sure that's the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this site config. It basically prevents Nginx responding to requests via IP. The "default_server" directive is the key part.

```
# This just prevents Nginx picking a random default server if it doesn't know which server block to send a request to
server {
  listen      80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return      444; # This means "go away", effectively

  access_log off; log_not_found off; # Optional
}
```

Comment: This works. I have a separate server file for each of my sites and I just put that `return 444` in my default one. Seems to work! thx!

Answer (score 0):

Although its possible to do what you want using a bunch of regex matches for the requested URL, I would avoid access via the IP to the parent (html) directory because:-

- It will be too easy to mess up in future (security)
- It will be hard to troubleshoot
- Some websites contain absolute links or links relative to / that will not be correct

Instead, to test sites before you get the domain configured and available, simply:-

- configure NGINX like you normally do
- add an entry in the host file on your client PC to resolve the name to the correct IP.

On Linux the hosts file is `/etc/hosts`

On Windows the hosts file is `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Here's a sample hosts file entry `216.58.216.78  www.myfunkysite.com`